# Integral $\int_{0}^{i}z\sin{z} \operatorname dz$

Tags: integration

Find this complex integral 
$$I=\int_{0}^{i}z\sin{z}dz=\dfrac{5\pi^2}{96}?$$
where $i^2=-1$

My try: use 
$$\sin{z}=\dfrac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$$
so
$$I=\dfrac{1}{2i}\int_{0}^{i}z(e^{iz}-e^{-iz})dz$$

My idea is true? Thank you

Thank you Christian Blatter help.and I have 
$$I=\int_{0}^{i}z\sin{z}dz=\int_{0}^{i}zd(-\cos{z})=z(-\cos{z})|_{0}^{i}+\int_{0}^{i}\cos{z}dz=-i\cos{i}+\sin{i}$$

so
$$I=-i\cos{i}+\sin{i}$$ can have simple form?

Comment: For me, the value $5\pi^{2}/96$ is a reminiscence of the [classical Ahmed's integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AhmedsIntegral.html). And of course, $I$ is not equal to this value since you can easily verify that $I$ is purely imaginary.

Comment: My frends tell us this $I$ equal to $\dfrac{5\pi^2}{96}$

Comment: so I guess maybe $$\sin{i}-i\cos{i}=\dfrac{5\pi^2}{96}$$?

Comment: Definitely, we have $$\sin i - i \cos i = i(\sinh 1 - \cosh 1) = -\frac{i}{e}.$$ You can use your favorite math program to test it numerically. This is not even a real number. I strongly suspect either you misunderstood what your friend said, or he/she was wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A hint: Find a primitive $F$ of the function $f(z):=z\sin z$. To this end find a primitive of the real function $f(x):=x\sin x$ in the usual way and check whether its "complexified version" works. Your integral is then simply $=F(i)-F(0)$.

Comment: Thank you ,I have edit from your methods, and I ask you $\sin{i}-i\cos{i}$ is simple form,